# Facebook GraphQL use in Postman as me?

Tags: facebook, graphql, postman

For the purpose of searching admin activity in a group I manage, can I authenticate as myself in Postman so that I can try to run some GraphQL as me? And if so, how?

Comment: Not clear what exactly you are trying to ask here; but for testing API calls, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ exists. You can also handle the login & permission granting part in there for such purposes.

Comment: Can I get my (as in my personal login) access token? Or is that hidden internally?

Comment: Yes, of course.